# fread() only copies the first character into the target buffer

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof, fread, dereference

I want to read the content of a .txt file and store it in a buffer.
To read the file I use `fread()`.

The [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) says:

> " On success, fread() and fwrite() return the number of items read
> or written.  This number equals the number of bytes transferred
> only when size is 1."

The problem I encounter is, that in the following code the function call returned 216 bytes. But in the final buffer the content consists of only a single char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool readFile(const char* pFileName, char* outFile) {
    FILE* myFile;
    myFile = fopen(pFileName, "r");
    if (myFile == NULL) {
        printf("File could not be opened.");
        return false;
    }

    printf("Size of my file: %d\n",sizeof(*myFile));
    printf("Size of output buffer %d\n",sizeof(outFile));
    printf("sizeof(*outFile) / sizeof(outFile) %d\n",sizeof(*myFile) / sizeof(myFile[0]));
    size_t res = fread(outFile, sizeof(*outFile), sizeof(*outFile)/sizeof((outFile)[0]), myFile);
    printf("freadResult: %d\n", res*sizeof(*myFile));
    fclose(myFile);

    return true;
}

int main(){

    char* fileName = "test.txt"; 
    char* outFile = (char*)malloc(4096);

    bool result = readFile(fileName, outFile);
    if(!result){
        printf("Error\n");
    } else {
        printf("Success\n");
        for(char* tmp = outFile; *tmp != '\0' ; ++tmp){
            printf("%c", *tmp);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Programm finished\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The test.txt file has the following three lines as content:

```
I was
opened
successfully!
```

If I build and execute the readFileTest I get the following output:

```
$ gcc readFileTest.c -o readFileTest
$ ./readFileTest 
>Size of my File: 216
>Size of output Buffer 8
>sizeof(*outFile) / sizeof(outFile) 1
>freadResult: 216
>Success
>I
>Programm finished
```

Comment: 'printf("Size of my file: %d\n",sizeof(*myFile));' no.

Comment: How should `readFile()` know that `outFile` has 4096 bytes of space? (It cannot.)

Comment: 'printf("Size of output buffer %d\n",sizeof(outFile));' no.

Comment: 'printf("freadResult: %d\n", res*sizeof(*myFile));' no.

Comment: To clarify the previous comments by someone else: The `sizeof` operator will return a value of type `size_t`. The correct `printf` conversion format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`, not `%d`. By using `%d` instead, your program is invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: I read it like this on the manpage:  `size_t ret = fread(buffer, sizeof(*buffer), ARRAY_SIZE(buffer), fp);` with  `#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]))`

Comment: Yes, `sizeof( *buffer ), ARRAY_SIZE( buffer )` works *if buffer is a locally defined array*. If `buffer` is `malloc`ed, or an array passed to a different function, that will no longer work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line

```
size_t res = fread(outFile, sizeof(*outFile), sizeof(*outFile)/sizeof((outFile)[0]), myFile);
```

the expression `sizeof(*outFile)` is equivalent to the expression `sizeof(char)` (the type of the variable `outFile` is `char *` so the type of the expression `*outFile` that is the same as `outFile[0]` is `char`) and equal to `1`. At the same time the expression `sizeof(*outFile)/sizeof((outFile)[0])` is equivalent to `sizeof(char)/sizeof(char )` and a;so is equal to `1`.

You need to pass to the function the actual size of the dynamically allocated array and use it within the function.

Pay attention to that to output values of `sizeof` operator you have to use the conversion specifier `zu` instead of `d` in calls of printf and in this call

```
printf("Size of my file: %d\n",sizeof(*myFile));
```

the expression `sizeof(*myFile)` yields the size of the structure `FILE`. It is not the size of the file.